# Can a player play on more than one team in the USATE?

Tags: rules, tournament, team

Can a Chess Player play on more than one team either as a regular player or as an "alternate" in the USATE 2016?

Comment: The webpage of the tournament does not seem to specify. I believe it should not be possible, but just write to the organizers and they will clarify.